# Xcode cannot initialize parameter of type 'GKPhotoSize'

Tags: xcode, parameters, initialization

More specifically I am getting the error "Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'GKPhotoSize *' with an |value of type 'int'"

and the line in my ISN_GameCenter.mm looks like:

```
void _ISN_loadGKPlayerPhoto(char* playerId, int size) {
    NSString* mPlayerId = [ISN_DataConvertor charToNSString:playerId];
    [[ISN_GameCenterManager sharedInstance] loadImageForPlayerWithPlayerId:mPlayerId size:size];
}
```

The parameter is being passed to this argument:

```
- (void) loadImageForPlayerWithPlayerId:(NSString *)playerId size:(GKPhotoSize) size;
```

I have no idea why this started happening and all the cannot initialize parameter of type on Stack doesnt reference this particular case. I have no idea why this started happening or how to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chang the size to GKPhotoSizeNormal or to GKPhotoSizeSmall, it will work. It depends on which size you want for your photo.

```
void _ISN_loadGKPlayerPhoto(char* playerId, int size) {
    NSString* mPlayerId = [ISN_DataConvertor charToNSString:playerId];
    [[ISN_GameCenterManager sharedInstance] loadImageForPlayerWithPlayerId:mPlayerId size:GKPhotoSizeNormal];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to GKPhotoSizeSmall and it worked.

Comment: Can you explain me how (or where) I can set this size? In Unity Editor Build Settings? In XCode? Do I have to redo that change everytime I build? And last but not least: What is that GKPhotoSize about? I'm not using Game Center in my app.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention: I'm using Unity Game Engine and the build files for iOS are generated. So I can not simply change the generated files ...

Comment: If you change it in Xcode youll have to change it every time you build. I found the ISN_GameCenter.mm file in Unity and changed it there so that it would always be applied when built.